# Something wrong with this definition of factorial with structural recursion?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming

In [The Algebra of Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013507245X) page 5, the authors defined structural recursion `foldn (c, h)` over natural numbers:

```
f  0    = c
f (n+1) = h (f n)
```

They then went on to defin factorial as follows:

```
fact = outr . foldn ((0, 1), f)
outr (m, n) = n
f (m, n) = (m + 1, (m + 1) * n)
```

This doesn't seem right, first of all, `foldn ((0, 1), f)` does not comply to its definition, secondly, this fold will never terminate, will it?

Comment: 1. Questions about code are normally off-topic for CS.SE (but might be on-topic for StackOverflow if you describe what you've tried to resolve this on your own).  See our [help].  2. What have you tried?  We expect you to put in a significant effort to solve the question on your own before asking.  In this particular example, have you tried running it on a few examples?  Seems like you should be able to very quickly resolve your own question by just running the code in a suitable interpreter on a few inputs and see whether it terminates or not and whether it produces the right answer.

Comment: These are not code, the are math equations.

Comment: @qed It is code, it's a (functional) program to compute the factorial function. Equations neither terminate nor fail to terminate, they are not expressions of computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition is correct. The syntax is almost Haskell code, so you can run it in a Haskell interpreter:

```
foldn (c, h) = g where
  g 0 = c
  g n = h (g (n - 1))

fact = outr . foldn ((0, 1), f)
outr (m, n) = n
f (m, n) = (m + 1, (m + 1) * n)
```

Usage in ghci:

```
Prelude> :load fact.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( fact.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> fact 0
1
*Main> fact 1
1
*Main> fact 2
2
*Main> fact 3
6
*Main> fact 4
24
*Main> fact 5
120
```

I don't know what you mean by “`foldn ((0, 1), f)` does not comply to its definition. If you mean that it's missing an argument, then this is not a problem. It's a function waiting to be applied. `foldn` is a [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function: it takes an argument and returns a function, which itself takes an argument and returns something; this makes `foldn` look like a function that takes two arguments (the first of which is a pair).

You can't evaluate `foldn ((0, 1), f)` any further (except to replace it by an anonymous function for which there is no source syntax) because its definition is by case on its argument: there's no way to know which one of `g 0 = …` or `g (n+1) = …` to use until you know whether the argument is 0.

Once you pass an argument, you can evaluate the call.

```
foldn ((0, 1), f) 0 = (0, 1)
```

so

```
fact 0 = (outr . foldn ((0, 1), f)) 0
       = outr (foldn ((0, 1), f) 0)
       = outr (0, 1)
       = 1

fact 1 = (outr . foldn ((0, 1), f)) 1
       = outr (foldn ((0, 1), f) 1)
       = outr (f (foldn ((0, 1), f) 0))
       = outr (f (0, 1))
       = outr (0 + 1, (0 + 1) * 1)
       = outr (1, 1)
       = 1
```

I'll let you work out other values by yourself.

The computation always terminates, regardless of the function `h` (assuming only that `h` terminates), by a simple induction argument: each nested call to `foldn` is applied to a smaller integer. For any nonnegative parameter, eventually the argument will be 0 which does not involve recursion.